# SAPUI5 : How to create a sideBar in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

SAPUI5 : How to create a sideBar in SAPUI5 ? I have to create a collapseable side bar on the right. please help me here.

Note: I have to do this without using Ux3 or commons libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for control `Dynamic Side Content`, which probably does exactly what you want. Please find a [demo in the UI5 Explored app](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.DynamicSideContentProduct/preview).

[image: Screenshot of Dynamic Side Content demo]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively there's the `sap.ui.ux3.Shell`- see the example here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/ux3/demokit/Shell.html

Comment: Thanks!   But I have to do this without using Ux3 or commons libraries.

Comment: In that case, what's wrong with @jpenninkhof's answer?

Comment: It would have been helpful to state your restrictions in the original question :-(

Answer (score 0):

**Is that what you want?**
    https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.DynamicSideContentProduct/preview

**if not**

html or xml or js

```
<div id="closeBtn">close</div>
<div id="sideBar">......</div>
```

js (jquery)

```
var open = true;

$("#closeBtn").on("click",function(){

   if(open){
         $("#sidebar).animate(    {'height' : '200'},300};
   }
   else{`enter code here`
         $("#sidebar).animate({'height' : '0'},300};
   }
}
```